# how to speed up correctly using Numba?

Tags: python-3.x, numba

I am currently working on the speed up for my python functions.

```
def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2)


def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) * 
                           np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) *
                           np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2)

def distance(u,v,lon1,lat1):
    lat2, lon2 = lat1.copy(), lon1.copy()
    lat2[v>0], lat2[v<0], = lat1[v>0]+1, lat1[v<0]-1,
    lon2[u>0], lon2[u<0], = lon1[u>0]+1, lon1[u<0]-1,
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    return dlon, dlat
```

As you can see, this is the simple code that is based on the numpy.
I read most of the articles on the internet, what they said are just put @numba.jit as the decorator in front of the function, and then I can use Numba to speed up my code.

Here is the test I have done.

```
u = np.random.randn(10000)
v = np.random.randn(10000)
lon1 = np.random.uniform(-99,-96,10000)
lat1 = np.random.uniform( 23, 25,10000)
print(u)
```

```
%%timeit
for i in range(10000):
    distance(u,v,lon1,lat1)
```

5.61 s ± 58.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#### Add Numba decorator

```
@numba.njit()
def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2)

@numba.njit()
def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) * 
                           np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) *
                           np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2)

@numba.njit()
def distance(u, v, lon1, lat1, R=6.371*1e6):
    lat2, lon2 = lat1.copy(), lon1.copy()
    lat2[v>0], lat2[v<0], = lat1[v>0]+1, lat1[v<0]-1,
    lon2[u>0], lon2[u<0], = lon1[u>0]+1, lon1[u<0]-1,
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    return d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon), d_lat(dlat)
```

```
%%timeit
for i in range(10000):
    a,b = distance(u,v,lon1,lat1)
```

7.76 s ± 64.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

As you can see above, the computational speed of my Numba case is slower than my pure python case. Could anyone please help me to solve this?

ps: version of numba
llvmlite  0.32.0rc1
numba     0.49.0rc2

### ------  Computational Test Regarding the macroeconomist's answer.  ------

According to his answer, even Numba now is smart enough, if we want the code is going to be Numba-decorated, it is better to use plain "Fortran"/"C" type of styles. Below is presenting the computational time comparison between different methods that I was thinking.

```
def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2)

def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) * 
                           np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) *
                           np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2)

def distance(u,v,lon1,lat1):
    lat2, lon2 = lat1.copy(), lon1.copy()
    lat2[v>0], lat2[v<0], = lat1[v>0]+1, lat1[v<0]-1,
    lon2[u>0], lon2[u<0], = lon1[u>0]+1, lon1[u<0]-1,
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    return dlon, dlat
```

```
%%timeit
for i in range(10000):
    distance(u,v,lon1,lat1)
```

#### 54 s ± 485 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
@numba.jit(nogil=True)
def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2)

@numba.jit(nogil=True)
def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) * 
                           np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) *
                           np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2)

def distance(u, v, lon1, lat1, R=6.371*1e6):
    lat2, lon2 = lat1.copy(), lon1.copy()
    lat2[v>0], lat2[v<0], = lat1[v>0]+1, lat1[v<0]-1,
    lon2[u>0], lon2[u<0], = lon1[u>0]+1, lon1[u<0]-1,
    dlat = lat2 - lat1
    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    return d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon), d_lat(dlat)
```

```
%%timeit
for i in range(10000):
    a,b = distance(u,v,lon1,lat1)
```

#### 1min 21s ± 815 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2)

def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6):
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) * 
                           np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) *
                           np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2)

@numba.njit(nogil=True)
def distance(u, v, lon1, lat1, R=6.371*1e6):
    def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6):
        return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2)             
    def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6):
        return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) * 
                               np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) *
                               np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2)
    lat2, lon2 = lat1.copy(), lon1.copy()
    lat2[v>0], lat2[v<0], = lat1[v>0]+1, lat1[v<0]-1,
    lon2[u>0], lon2[u<0], = lon1[u>0]+1, lon1[u<0]-1,
    dlat = d_lat(lat2 - lat1)
    dlon = d_lon(lat1,lat2,lon2 - lon1)
    return dlon, dlat
```

```
%%timeit
for i in range(10000):
    a,b = distance(u,v,lon1,lat1)
```

#### 1min 2s ± 239 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
@numba.njit() 
def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6): 
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2) 

@numba.njit() 
def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6): 
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) *  
                           np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) * 
                           np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2) 

@numba.njit() 
def distance(u, v, lon1, lat1): 
    lon2 = np.empty_like(lon1) 
    lat2 = np.empty_like(lat1) 
    dlon = np.empty_like(lon1) 
    dlat = np.empty_like(lat1) 

    for i in range(len(v)): 
        vi = v[i] 
        if vi > 0: 
            lat2[i] = lat1[i]+1 
            dlat[i] = 1 
        elif vi < 0: 
            lat2[i] = lat1[i]-1 
            dlat[i] = -1 
        else: 
            lat2[i] = lat1[i] 
            dlat[i] = 0 

    for i in range(len(u)): 
        ui = u[i] 
        if ui > 0:  
            lon2[i] = lon1[i]+1 
            dlon[i] = 1 
        elif ui < 0: 
            lon2[i] = lon1[i]-1 
            dlon[i] = -1 
        else: 
            lon2[i] = lon1[i] 
            dlon[i] = 0 

    return d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon), d_lat(dlat)
```

```
%%timeit
for i in range(10000):
    distance(u,v,lon1,lat1)
```

#### 35.9 s ± 537 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: You may want to consider timing each function separately with and without Jit to see if you get improvement using Numba. The documentation does say that Jit does not always improve performance and can actually be slower due to strong typing the variables. Some times Jit does produce gains at scale while being slower with small data sets. Lastly, you may want to try using signatures in your @numba.jit as it can improve performance by letting Numba know what data types it will be receiving.

Comment: signatures? like @numba.njit(float32, float32, float32, float32) for the function distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues that jump out.

First, your calculations in the `distance` function are unnecessarily complicated, and written in a style (with lots of fancy indexing e.g. `lat2[v>0]`) that may not be ideal for the Numba compiler. Although Numba is getting smarter, I find that there is still a high return to writing code in a simple, loop-oriented way.

Second, Numba can be slowed down a little by optional arguments. I found that this was true primarily for the optional `R` in your `distance` function.

Fixing these two issues - in particular, replacing your vectorized code with simpler loops that minimize operations - we get code of the form

```
@numba.njit() 
def d_lat(dlat,R=6.371*1e6): 
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlat)/2)**2) 

@numba.njit() 
def d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon,R=6.371*1e6): 
    return 2 * R * np.sqrt(np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat1)) *  
                           np.cos(np.deg2rad(lat2)) * 
                           np.sin(np.deg2rad(dlon)/2)**2) 

@numba.njit() 
def distance(u, v, lon1, lat1): 
    lon2 = np.empty_like(lon1) 
    lat2 = np.empty_like(lat1) 
    dlon = np.empty_like(lon1) 
    dlat = np.empty_like(lat1) 

    for i in range(len(v)): 
        vi = v[i] 
        if vi > 0: 
            lat2[i] = lat1[i]+1 
            dlat[i] = 1 
        elif vi < 0: 
            lat2[i] = lat1[i]-1 
            dlat[i] = -1 
        else: 
            lat2[i] = lat1[i] 
            dlat[i] = 0 

    for i in range(len(u)): 
        ui = u[i] 
        if ui > 0:  
            lon2[i] = lon1[i]+1 
            dlon[i] = 1 
        elif ui < 0: 
            lon2[i] = lon1[i]-1 
            dlon[i] = -1 
        else: 
            lon2[i] = lon1[i] 
            dlon[i] = 0 

    return d_lon(lat1,lat2,dlon), d_lat(dlat)
```

On my (slower) system, this decreases the time after the initial cost of compilation from around 7 seconds to around 4 seconds. At that point, I believe the cost is dominated by the raw cost of all the functions `np.sin`, `np.cos`, `np.exp`, etc.

Comment: Do you think if I add the nogil=True or parallel=True these two arguments will advance speed up my code?